# Is making a software for beer related accessories sinful?

Tags: halal-haram, work, alcohol

I work as a freelancer and my client wants to design his website (The website is already made, he wants me to design). The website only sells magnets that fit on top of a beer machine that you can buy and have at home. The beer machine is called a “perfect draft”. These magnets show the type of beer that you have inside the machine on the handle.

At the moment he only sells one type of magnet, which is the beer ones. Some people sell sports teams ones but he doesn't have a plan on doing that yet.

Please guide me on what Islam says about such work that is not directly related to the production of beer or even selling but selling a part/accessory